# ZF2: Class 'Payum\Sofort\Payment\SofortUeberWeisung' not found

Tags: class, controller, zend-framework2, payum

Here is my controller that is using the class from Payum Module in vendor.

```
<?php
    namespace Orders\Controller;
    use Payum\Sofort;
    use Payum\Sofort\Payment\SofortUeberWeisung;

    class PaymentController extends AbstractActionController
     {

    protected $entityManager;

    public function sofortAction()
    {
      $Sofortueberweisung = new SofortUeberWeisung($configkey);

        $Sofortueberweisung->setAmount(10.21);
        $Sofortueberweisung->setCurrencyCode('EUR');
        //$Sofortueberweisung->setSenderSepaAccount('88888888', '12345678', 'Max Mustermann');
        $Sofortueberweisung->setSenderCountryCode('DE');
        $Sofortueberweisung->setReason('Testueberweisung', 'Verwendungszweck');
        $Sofortueberweisung->setSuccessUrl('http://www.google.de', true);
        $Sofortueberweisung->setAbortUrl('http://www.google.de');
        // $Sofortueberweisung->setNotificationUrl('http://www.google.de', 'loss,pending');
        // $Sofortueberweisung->setNotificationUrl('http://www.yahoo.com', 'loss');
        // $Sofortueberweisung->setNotificationUrl('http://www.bing.com', 'pending');
        // $Sofortueberweisung->setNotificationUrl('http://www.sofort.com', 'received');
        // $Sofortueberweisung->setNotificationUrl('http://www.youtube.com', 'refunded');
        // $Sofortueberweisung->setNotificationUrl('http://www.youtube.com', 'untraceable');
        $Sofortueberweisung->setNotificationUrl('http://www.twitter.com');
        $Sofortueberweisung->setCustomerprotection(true);

             $Sofortueberweisung->sendRequest();

            if($Sofortueberweisung->isError()) {
                //SOFORT-API didn't accept the data
                echo $Sofortueberweisung->getError();
            } else {
                //buyer must be redirected to $paymentUrl else payment cannot be successfully completed!
                $paymentUrl = $Sofortueberweisung->getPaymentUrl();
                header('Location: '.$paymentUrl);
            }
        }

    }
```

And The class is here in the Payum\Sofort\Payment folder

```
<?php

   namespace Sofort\Payment;
   use Payum\Sofort\Core\SofortLibMultipay;

   class SofortUeberWeisung extends SofortLibMultipay {

    public function __construct($configKey) {
    parent::__construct($configKey);
    $this->_parameters['su'] = array();
   }
  }
```

Why it is still showing the class is not found in Controller But i can see it is going to the class when i go to the definition of the new Class in my controller. Like the image attached.

Is there anything wrong i am doing please correct me,
 [image]

Comment: @Dymen1 Can you check this one?

Answer (score 0):

You are importing `SofortUeberWeisung` class in your controller which is spcified under this `Sofort\Payment` namespace, but not under this `Payum\Sofort\Payment`. So that should be in your controller

```
use Sofort\Payment\SofortUeberWeisung;
```